# Android layout not showing scroll bar in landscape view

Tags: android, layout, scroll

this is the layout iam using and it  seems fine in portrait , however as soon as i position it as landscape, i am unable to introduce scrolling and the lower most buttons, i.e. login and reset float to the top overlapping other elements.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Callsign"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#00ff10"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="65sp"
                android:layout_height="65sp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#00ff10"
                android:textSize="45sp"    />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="65sp"
                android:layout_height="65sp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#00ff10"
                android:textSize="45sp"    />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="65sp"
                android:layout_height="65sp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#00ff10" 
                android:textSize="45sp"   />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="65sp"
                android:layout_height="65sp"
                android:text="0" 
                android:textColor="#00ff10"
                android:textSize="45sp"   />
        </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/login"
                        android:layout_width="82dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:text="Login"
                        android:textColor="#00ff10" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/reset"
                        android:layout_width="82dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:text="Reset"
                        android:textColor="#00ff10" />
                </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

[image: In Portrait]
[image: In Landscape]

Comment: For that you need to add <ScrollView >.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scroll layout

and in manifest file inside activity tag use

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"

Comment: Hi SSK, i indeed used Scroll view and seems to have worked. But i have the problem of overlapping with two buttons. I have updated my layout.xml. and pasted my portrait and landscape views .Is there any other configuration that needs to be done?

Comment: Use Linear Layout instead of relative and set android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: Excellent SSK. This is what i wanted.